# Provide user name and password for SQL Server trusted connection

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

Using SQL Server 2014, we have a domain user added to the SQL Server CompanyName / UserName, and an app in C# which uses trusted connection to connect to the database.

Now when running in a domain environment, this works fine however when I run on my local machine it does not work which is not part of the domain but has access to SQL Server.

I've added a SQL Server user which requires a username and password just to test I can connect to SQL Server, and this works fine from my local machine (so I can connect to the server).

My question: is it possible to connect to SQL Server with the domains credentials from my local machine in my C# app? (i.e provide the user name and password of my domain through my local machine).

What cannot be done. Adding a SQL Server user with user name and password. Adding the local machines credentials to SQL Server. I have to use the domains user name and password.

Comment: That isn't how a trusted connection works. if you want to use an AD user that isn't the one that the application is running under, you need to use impersonation.

Comment: thanks a little bit of search on it and i found the solution below. Can adapt it for c# code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Larnu

the command for running an app using cmd is. it does however ask for password separately which apparently is built into Windows security.

run cmd as admin and

runas /netonly /user:domain\username "Path of file to be executed"